# Yii2 adminpanel authorization

Tags: yii2

I want my project`s program should be like this:

I have divided admin into 2 groups

1. **Mainadmin**
2. **Secondadmin**

1) There is a mainadmin and a number of secondadmins. Main admin can create, edit secondadmins and while creating and editing, mainadmin should be able to create passwords and usernames for secondadmins.

2) When Secondadmins will login they should see only a page.With this page secondadmins can create their child admins and give them their own usernames and passwords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Yii2 Roles](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html) to build your own way to restrict access and [Access Control class](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-accesscontrol.html)

You can do something like that:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['login', 'mainpage'],
                    'roles' => ['secondadmin'],
                ],
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['mainadmin'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

In this controller, mainadmin can do any action, but second admin only can use login and mainpage actions.